# Inequalities in functions

Tags: graphing-functions, functional-inequalities

$f(x)=x^8-x^5+x^2-x+1$.

Prove that $f(x)>0$, for all $x \in\Bbb R$

I tried by calculating first derivative to find maxima or minima but it didn't worked.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

It amounts to showing that, for an $x$,
$$x^8+x^2+1 >x^5+x.$$
If $x\le 0 $, this is obvious. If $x > 0$, consider the cases $x\ge 1$ and $x<1$. Can you show that each term in the r.h.s. is individually less than another term in the l.h.s.?